# Web.config transform not being performed in .NetCore 6 webapi service

Tags: .net-core, web-config, appsettings, web.config-transform

My dotNetCore 6 webapi webservice is hosted on an internal IIS webserver. The web.config has two transforms web.Debug.config and web.Release.config. The web.config is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="bin\Debug\net6.0\SMARTapi.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="false" hostingModel="InProcess">
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="development" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

The web.Release.config is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <location>
        <system.webServer>
            <aspNetCore>
                <environmentVariables>
                    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="production" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
                </environmentVariables>
            </aspNetCore>
        </system.webServer>
    </location> 
</configuration>
```

When I Publish using the Release profile I do not get the transformed web.config. I get the three separate files web.config, web.Debug.config and web.Release.config. I suspect because of this I also get three appsettings files. These are appsettings.json, appsettings.development.json and appsettings.production.json. I think I should only be getting appsettings.json and appsettings.production.json or just the one which would be a combination of appsettings.json and appsettings.production.json.

Q: Why is my transform not working? and once transform is fixed will appsettings get fixed?

Comment: I assume you're aware that `.pubxml` files are MSBuild project files in-of themselves? Hence, you'll need to re-define the MSBuild Properties, Items, Tasks and Targets for the "publish builds" the same way you do for local build and debug.

Comment: _"Why is my transform not working?"_ - You haven't shown us your code where you configure the XDT transform. XDTs don't run by themselves.

Comment: `appsettings.(env).json` is loaded based on the `Environment` config value: this is done in the default host building for ASP.NET Core web apps. While there is only one `web.config` and those transforms need to be done as part of your deployment process. In DevOps CI/CD there is a task for this, plus (depending on options) it can be done by the publish step by MSBuild (IIRC). Summary: web.config and appsettings are fundamentally different approaches; the former very much legacy just for IIS setup.

Comment: @Dai I have supplied the web.config and the web.Release.config. The web.Release.config has the elements that need transforming. In old .net frameworks that all I had albeit the web.configs had connection strings and other settings which now in .netCore are in my appsettings files.

Comment: @Mych XDT-on-Build requires at least one of your MSBuild files to have `<ProjectProfileTransformFileName>` defined in it - you haven't shown us that. The value of the  `<ProjectProfileTransformFileName>` property is how the XDT determines which `Web.{NAME}.config` to apply to your `Web.config`. For example, in one of my legacy .NET 4 projects, I have a `DeployToStaging.pubxml` file with `<ProjectProfileTransformFileName>Staging-West</ProjectProfileTransformFileName>` in it - and I have a `Web.Staging-West.config` file in my project dir.